# AWS Glue how do I truncate or delete rows in the table pre-processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a glue process that extracts and loads however prior to the load I would like to truncate/delete from the table

I looked at this link
 https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sql-commands-redshift-glue-job/#

Seems like this is available for redshift only - the other option is to get connection details and open a connection directly.

Is there something I can use in the spark context (don't think glue is an option ) to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a Lambda function on Glue event

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/automating-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-events.html